# Get stream, System message customisation stream-chat

Tags: node.js, reactjs, getstream-chat

community
I implemented stream-chat & stream-chat-react [getStream](https://getstream.io/)

Hi, I want to show the system message on some events
For Ex: User A added User B to the chat (Here user A and User B is the name of both user but I don't want to send those message as it is because I want if user A changes their name to USER X then those previous messages also updated.) I want guidance on how I can achieve this.

Stream is allowing me to send system messages with the addMemberToChannel event but I am not able to find how I can use it for my specific case.

Expected Output:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your case, you will avoid saving hardcoded data in the message's `text` property.

First, you create a system message on adding a user to a channel like this:

```js
channel.addMembers([userId], {
  text: 'added_users',
  mentioned_users: [userId],
});
```

With the `addMembers` method on a `channel` object, you can add members to a channel and also pass a message object.

The message object accepts the message `text` and the `mentioned_users` properties.

You can use **added_users** or any text that you want to keep as a standard message for adding-members-system-message. You'll see why I use "added_users" in a second.

The `Channel` component renders system messages using the [`EventComponent`](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-react/blob/master/src/components/EventComponent/EventComponent.tsx). This component displays the `text` of the system message, with the date and some added styles.

[image: Default system Message]

You can create a [custom event message component](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/react/custom-code-examples/system_message/) for your **added_users** message. This component can look like this:

```
import { EventComponent } from 'stream-chat-react';

function CustomEventMessage(props) {
  const { message } = props;

  const { text, mentioned_users, user } = message;

  if (text === 'added_users') {
    const message = user?.name + ' added ' + mentioned_users[0].name;

    return (
      <div className="str-chat__message--system">
        <div className="str-chat__message--system__text">
          <div className="str-chat__message--system__line"></div>
          <p>{message}</p>
          <div className="str-chat__message--system__line"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  // use the default event component
  return <EventComponent {...props} />;
}
```

The `CustomEventMessage` component above accepts a `message` object prop which has the:

- `text`: system message text
- `mentioned_users`: mentioned users in the message
- `user`: user who triggered the message

Next, you check if the `text` is **added_users**. If it is, then you provide a custom UI and message, which consists of the name of the user who triggered the message and the mentioned user (who was added to the channel)

I also used classnames from Stream's stylesheets so that I don't have to build mine.

Next, you add this component to the `Channel` component:

```
<Channel MessageSystem={CustomEventMessage}>
  // ...
</Channel>
```

The message will now read as "Person X added Person Y" as seen in the image below:

[image: Custom message for added users]

If the `text` is not **added_users**, you pass the props to the default `EventComponent`.

Since you're saving the `id` of the mentioned user and not hardcoding the text ("Person A added Person B"), you will also get updated details about the users, even when they update their information.